# How to count the numbers where the absolute value is greater than LOG2 cutoff with COUNTIFS in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I have an excel sheet with some numbers and I want to count the numbers where its absolute value is `>=LOG(y,2)`.

I know `COUNTIFS` can be used to find the numbers greater than a value, but I don't know how to include the `LOG`  and `ABS` functions into the formula.

For example my numbers, `x= 12,34,-15,-23,-5,45,-50`
and I want to count the numbers where the `ABS(x)>=LOG(y,2)` where Y can be variable, for example `y=3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best way I found:
There is not seems to be any other way.
You can hide the `=ABS` column if it helps...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Thats my best way:

English Excel Version

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ABS(A1:A7)>=LOG(32768,2)))
```

German Excel Version:

```
=SUMMENPRODUKT(--(ABS(A1:A7)>=LOG(32768;2)))
```

[image]